# Running python command from java code on mac

Tags: java, python

I am trying to run python command paster serve from Java code.
I want to run paster serve command from specific folder in new terminal. I tried following code after searching lots of things on stack overflow but that dint work.

```
String[] shellcmd = {
                 paster server conf/def.ini",
                    "/Users/shee/pythonAgent/"
                };

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shellcmd);
```

I am running this code from different folder and thats why its giving me error "Cannot run program "paster server conf/def.ini": error=2, No such file or directory" So, I want to start new terminal and go to the pythonAgent folder and then run this command.

Comment: well finally I could open new terminal but I am not sure now how I can run command in same window..
Following is the code that I used:-

String[] cmd = {"/usr/bin/open","-a","Terminal","/Users/shee/pythonAgent/"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

But, now I am trying to run paster serve conf/dev.ini command from same folder. Trying to do in 1 command.